# The W3SVC service on Server2012R2 failed to stop in the timeout period

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, svchost

Our Devs are trying to do a "push" and it is failing on a single IIS server (running Windows Server 2012 R2) because the push is unable to stop the **WWW Publishing Service** (W3SVC). We have been rebooting the Svr2012R2 VM as a workaround fix to the issue, but need to get to the heart of the problem.

[I read here that the issue could be linked to SvcHost.exe process](https://joelmansford.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/killing-the-right-svchostexe-process/), but am unsure at this point. Any help or feedback appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Svchost is just a generic container for launching services.

Comment: What methods or commands are they using to stop the service?

Comment: I've used 'net stop W3SVC -force' to try and stop the service, but once the service has failed to stop it does not work.

Comment: Apparently just re-configuring the App Pools fixed it, I've been told. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by installing updates, apparently there was some issue with one of the recent Windows updates:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345424/improvements-and-fixes-windows-8-1-and-server-2012-r2